# htaccess help needed on redirect in php with "unchanged" url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site where I redirect the user to a url, created within a SQL query based on what he entered. So when someone for instance enters http://www.example.com/Something, they are automatically redirected to something like http://www.example.com/Templates/12ES.html?ID=a_very_long_string&URI=Something.

This is all done in one PHP file, and the ID and URI parameters are dynamic. 
Is there a way to keep the URL the user entered in the browser while I let PHP do the redirecting silently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the .htaccess file in your project root and you're only expecting a single URL segment you could try something along these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /Templates/12ES.html?ID=a_very_long_string&URI=$1 [L]
```

So long as you don't set the R flag the address in the browser's address bar wont change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you show me how I can rewrite the above to take dynamic parameters? Because in my case /Templates/12ES.html can change, ID is a 32 char dynamic string and URI is also dynamic.